# R: Rgtk2: gwidgets: gWidgetsRGtk2

Tags: r, gwidgets

I would like to combo gWidgets(john verzani) with Rgtk2.
This could be used by anyone as a paradigm.

The algorithm is as follows:
STEP 1: Construct a gwindow (or a gframe)
STEP 2: Construct a GTK scrollable text view
STEP 3: Convert the last one into a gwidget
STEP 4: Add it into the gwindow (or into the gframe)

I wonder if this is a right thinking
while the problem I face is with the GTK scrollable text view:
I cannot make the scrollbars work.

The code in R is as follows:

```
###########################
# load libraries
library(RGtk2)
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)

# data set
x <- c(1:9)
y <- c(10:19)
z <- c(20:29)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
df.co <- capture.output(df)

###########################
# STEP 1, library(gWidgets)
# Construct a gwindow (or a gframe)
G.Window <- gwindow()

###########################
# STEP 2, library(RGtk2)
# Construct a GTK scrollable text view
Gtk.Text.View <- gtkTextViewNew(show = TRUE)

# create a table to attach the scrollbars
Gtk.Table.New <- gtkTableNew(2, 2, show = TRUE)

# construct the scrollbars
Gtk.H <- gtkHScrollbarNew()
Gtk.V <- gtkVScrollbarNew()

# attach the text view and the scrollbars to the table
gtkTableAttach(Gtk.Table.New, Gtk.Text.View, 0, 1, 0, 1)
gtkTableAttach(Gtk.Table.New, Gtk.H, 0, 1, 1, 2)
gtkTableAttach(Gtk.Table.New, Gtk.V, 1, 2, 0, 1)

# The scrollbars are not functional, for now.
# So I thought of constructing a viewport.
# The problem I face is that I cannot make the scrollbars work. 
Gtk.Viewport <- gtkViewportNew()

###########################
# STEP 3, library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
# Convert the table into a gwidget
G.Table.View <- as.gWidgetsRGtk2(Gtk.Table.New)

###########################
# STEP 4, library(gWidgets)
# Add the table into the gwindow (or into the gframe)
add(G.Window, Gtk.Table.New)

# STEP 5, make the buffer management
Gtk.Text.View.Get.Buffer <- gtkTextViewGetBuffer(Gtk.Text.View)

for (i in 1:length(df.co))
{
    Gtk.Text.Buffer.Get.Bounds <- gtkTextBufferGetBounds(Gtk.Text.View.Get.Buffer)
    Gtk.Text.Buffer.Insert <- gtkTextBufferInsert(Gtk.Text.View.Get.Buffer, iter=Gtk.Text.Buffer.Get.Bounds$end, text=paste(df.co[i], "\n",  sep="", collapse=""), len=-1)
    }

###########################
```

I do not want to use a GTK scrollable window,
since I want the GTK text/table widget after it is converted into a gWidget,
to enter also into a window (gWidget).

I also want to apologize if this is not a subject for stackoverflow. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right in that you can use `add()` to insert RGtk2 objects into a gWidgetsRGtk2 GUI. But in this case, you can likely save yourself some work with `getToolkitWidget()`:

```
library(RGtk2)
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")

w <- gwindow(); txt <- gtext("", cont=w)

text_view <- getToolkitWidget(txt)
buffer <- text_view$getBuffer()
...
```

To get your hands on the gtkScrollWindow object requires you to know that it is the parent of the text_view: `text_view$getParent()`.

One last comment, your step 3 works and should give your object the gWidgets methods, but isn't necessary. Just add the RGtk2 object. I did not include these "`as`" methods in the rewrite, gWidgets2 (on github and mostly working but not finished) as it didn't seem so useful.

Comment: I am really obliged for your answer. Thank you a lot. Apostolos