# Glade interface and gWidgets2

Tags: r, gwidgets

So, in relation with the three questions linked below, would somebody have more info on whether/how it is possible to load a glade UI into gWidgets2?

I managed to read the UI, based on the example given in Rgtk2, with something like that:

```
gladeFile <- system.file("t.test.glade",package="gWidgets2RGtk2")

builder <- gtkBuilder()
res <- builder$addFromFile(gladeFile)
if (!is.null(res$error))
  stop("ERROR: ", res$error$message)

builder$connectSignals(NULL)
```

I can then use it, in Rgtk2, as follows:

```
 window <- builder$getObject("window1")
 window$showAll()
```

How can I know convert the Rgtk2 objects to gWidgets2, in such a way that I can use, for instance, `svalue()` ? I.e. adding the gWidgets2 methods to RGtk2 objects, which used to be doable with `as.gWidgetsRGtk2` (as in the example file coming with gWidgets1) -- deprecated, alas, and removed from gWidgets2.

Thanks

Refs:
[R: gWidgetsRGtk2: gladeXMLNew() function not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855248/r-gwidgetsrgtk2-gladexmlnew-function-not-found)

[RGtk2 - missing gladexmlnew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259282/rgtk2-missing-gladexmlnew)

[R: Rgtk2: gwidgets: gWidgetsRGtk2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870635/r-rgtk2-gwidgets-gwidgetsrgtk2)

Comment: Sorry, not sure I can help with this one. It would be a reasonable thing to add and I'd happily take a pull request (I added an issue -- https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2RGtk2/issues/21 -- but don't see myself adding this any time soon.)

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer anyway...

Comment: I looked at the code in gWidgets1, and it looks doable. We'll see.